# Mongoose not updating when using stream()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to run an update and publish a message for each updated resource. It works fine when running as a standard mongoose query with a callback, but fails to have an effect using stream, even though the resources are output into the stream.

```
var discount = {
    startDate: process.env.START_DATE,
    endDate: process.env.END_DATE,
    funding: process.env.FUNDING, 
    percentage: process.env.PERCENTAGE
}


var connection = mongoose.createConnection(mongoEndpoint, config.mongo);
var Resources = connection.model('Resources', resourcesSchema);
var stream = Resources.update({_id:6375668}, { $push: { discounts: 'blob2' } }, { multi: true });

stream.on('data', function(resource) {
    console.log('Updated resource + published message',resource._id, discount)
    rabbit.publish('index-resource', resource);
});

stream.on('end', function() {
    console.log('Updated all resources in query');
    process.exit(0);
})


var ResourceSchema = module.exports = new Schema({
    _id: Number,
    discounts: Array
}, {versionKey: false});
```

Comment: Well [`.update()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) of course cannot return a [`.stream()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-stream), since that is a method on a `Query` object which is not what `.update()` returns. It's just a simple callback or promise and also does not return each modified document.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your resourcesSchema is undefined here?

`var Resources = connection.model('Resources', resourcesSchema);`

Comment: Nope. It's just that `.update()` does not return a [`stream`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html)